# Amazon Redshift Copy command does not work with special character

Tags: amazon-web-services, utf-8, amazon-redshift

I am using Amazon Redshift. My task is to load data from CSV to Redshift table.

I am using the COPY command. It is working for other data. This time I have data like `nóma` which contains special data.

Problem is that this data is getting converted to `n?ma`
when I use the `ACCEPTINVCHARS` parameter. I want the data to load  as it is.

When I use the INSERT statement, the data gets inserted properly.
But not when I am using the Redshift COPY command.

```
copy stage.teammateSFDCAccount_temp
from 's3://taasedwprod01/TeamMate/sfdcaccount.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=opadpasde;aws_secret_access_key=asdasdasd'
CSV ignoreheader as 1 
COMPUPDATE ON ACCEPTINVCHARS  MAXERROR AS 500 TRUNCATECOLUMNS*  ;
```

I tried using Encoding method parameter as UTF8 which did not worked for me. I also tried removing `ACCEPTINVCHARS` from the COPY command which resulted in not loading of data.

Comment: It could be that the data is being copied correctly without using `ACCEPTINVCHARS`, but the tool you are using to query Redshift is incorrectly displaying the characters. Check that your query tool is correctly handling UTF8, perhaps by inserting UTF8 data using the same tool and checking where it Selects correctly. Or, try a different query tool and see if it is actually working correctly. Also, did you check the [STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL.html) table to view the error message?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein Thanks for reply .  When i dont use ACCEPTINVCHARS it throws error , which means data is not getting loaded .

Comment: Look in the STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL table to view information about the error, which might help you debug.

Comment: String contains invalid or unsupported UTF8 codepoints. Bad UTF8 hex sequence: f3 6e 20 45 (error 4)

Comment: In that case, it appears that your input file is not valid UTF-8. You could try opening it in a UTF8-aware editor to verify the contents. If it looks good, save it to a new file and try importing it again.

Comment: What is see is data like this nóma there is something on o which is causing error